# How to make a burn effect like this photo

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]

How to make a burn effect in photoshop ? Is this effect created using a plugin in photoshop ?? or with any other software ?? please see the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are right, it's a plugin in Photoshop. The plugin called: "Fractalius"